# Wordpress container refuse to connect with mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I'm trying to setup wordpress, but wordpress container refuse to connect with mysql even thought when I change mysql to mariadb it works, so I don't know what should I do.

```
docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=pass --name wordpress --link wordpressdb:mysql -p 80:80 -v "$PWD/html":/var/www/html -d wordpress
```

this mysql command

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress  --name wordpressdb -v "$PWD/database":/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:latest
```

just a side note: I'm not allowed to use docker-composer

I'll appreciate any lead

Comment: I tried to reproduce this and in my case it was because the wordpress container wasn't able to handle the authentication mechanism: "The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]". This error was shown when I ran `docker logs wordpress`. So one solution would be `docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress  --name wordpressdb -v "$PWD/database":/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:latest --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` (notice the --default-authentication-plugin) or you could use `mysql:5.7`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a life saver